# xcode ios simulator does not show updated tab bar controller

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to create an ios app that consists of a tab bar controller with three buttons for 3 different pages. However, when I run the program the first few seconds shows it correctly but then it changes to a simple tab bar controller.

[on left is my tab bar controller and on the right is shown by the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOFWt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've edited the wrong storyboard. You have edited the Launch Screen storyboard. So during launch it shows your 3-tab interface. But then the app starts running and the Main storyboard is used. You didn't edit that one, so we are back to the plain vanilla Tabbed App template.

What you should have done was to edit the Main storyboard.